# How to change height of ViewPager according to current tab?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, layoutparams

I created a `DialogFragment` and there is a `ViewPager` inside it, which has 3 tabs. I want to change `ViewPager`'s height according to current tab. Here is my code:

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager); //TabLayout of Android Support Design Library
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(position);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mViewPager.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = mTabHeights.get(position);
    }
});
```

This isn't always useful. When I scroll the `ViewPager`, it can change the height dynamically according to current tab, everything works well. However, **when I click tabs inside `TabLayout`**, the page can't always change into tab I want to select. Besides, I can see some strange behaviors like:

1. The indicator scrolled to correct position, but textColors of both previous tab and tab I want to select don't change(I've set different colors for selected and unselected tabs by `TabLayout`'s API)
2. The indicator scrolled to correct position, colors are also right. `ViewPager`'s height is changed into correct number too, but tab's content is wrong(Sometimes it doesn't change, sometimes it becomes blank).

I found that onPageSelected() wasn't always called when I clicked tabs inside `TabLayout`. But if I move the code of changing `LayoutParams` of `ViewPager`, it can be called correctly.

So, what's the problem? **And How can I change ViewPager's height dynamically for different tabs?** Thanks for any answers/comments in advance!

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/rnevet/WCViewPager , it's a ViewPager that handles wrap_content and changes the height dynamically.

Comment: @Raanan I‘ve tried it before but it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: after setting `params.height`, I should call `mViewPager.requestLayout()` to make changes work immediately.

In many cases, `View#requestLayout()` or `View#setLayoutParams()` isn't needed. But this time, one of them should appear.